# Order Of The Intersection of Two Subfields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $E$ and $F$ be subfields of $GF(p^n)$. If $|E| = p^r$ and $|F| = p^s$, what is the order of $E\cap F$?

I read a corollary that "A finite field of order $p^n$ contains a unique subfield of order p^m for each $m$ | $n$ and no other subfields.

If that's the case, wouldn't that mean if two subfields have different orders, their intersection is $0$? So in this case, the order of  $E \cap F$ = $0$?

Comment: The intersection can't be zero since it contains the prime subfield $GF(p)$!  And anyway, $1 \in E, F$!

Comment: Very good point, thank you for the insight.

Comment: If you think about that corollary, you should be able to answer your question.

Comment: Any source of this corollary in any text or notes will be helpful!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Extended hint:</strike>

So if $t\mid r$, and $t\mid s$, then, by the result you quoted, both $E$ and $F$ contain a unique copy of $GF(p^t)$. But also $GF(p^n)$ contains a unique copy of $GF(p^t)$, which means that the copies of $GF(p^t)$ inside $E$ (resp. $F$) must coincide with the one in $GF(p^n)$, and thus be contained in the intersection $E\cap F$.

In view of this the intersection $E\cap F$ is a copy of $GF(p^\ell)$, where $\ell=\gcd(r,s)$.

Comment: So if $E$ and $F$ contain a unique copy of $GF(p^t)$ and $GF(p^n)$ also contains a unique copy of $GF(p^t)$ then $|E \cap F|$ $\geq$ $p^t$, and the intersection also contains the prime subfield $GF(p)$ as well. So... $|E \cap F| = p^t + p$ in this case?

Comment: @James: The prime field is contained in all the copies of $GF(p^t)$. You should also realize that the intersection has to be a subfield. The question is: which subfield? Or what is the biggest common subfield?

Comment: so with that. Using your example $GF(p^t)$, wouldn't the biggest subfield ($E \cap F$) just be the biggest $t$ that divides $r$, $s$ and $n$?

Comment: Correct, @James!

Comment: Thank you for the hints, helped me out. :)